# unique_together is not working with self referencing foreign key?

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self",
                               blank=True,
                               null=True,
                               related_name='children',
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [
            ('parent', 'name'),
        ]
```

In this model I am able to create multiple objects with

```
Category.objects.create(name="cat1", parent=None) # 
Category.objects.create(name="cat1", parent=None) 
# unique_together constraint should not 
# allow this second object's reaction, but it is; 
# behavior is the same even when the parent is not None.
```

Django version I am using is `3.0.8`
Postgres 12.3
psycopg2-binary 2.8.5

Update:

```
Category.objects.create(name="cat1", parent=obj) # 
Category.objects.create(name="cat1", parent=obj)
```

second object or record is getting created even when
parent is not None.

```
In [2]: Category2.objects.create(name="cat1")                            
Out[2]: <Category2: cat1>

In [3]: Category2.objects.create(name="cat1")                            
Out[3]: <Category2: cat1>

In [4]: par1 = Category2.objects.create(name="cat1")                     

In [6]: par1 = Category2.objects.create(name="cat2", parent=par1)        

In [7]: par2 = Category2.objects.create(name="cat2", parent=par1)
```

This question not a duplicate, it is not related to nullable foreign keys as explained in the question.

Comment: in my case the I am able  create records even with not-null fields values

Comment: Can you provide an example of the error occurring when non-null values are used?

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Comment: yes I did run them

Comment: javed: databases do not consider two `NULL`s to be the same. So `NULL` will not "breach" the uniqness constraint.

Comment: @IainShelvington: sorry, autocompletion :S

Comment: @javed: exactly what database do you use? Not all databases enforce all checks. Some simply ignore `CHECK ...` clauses, etc.

Comment: I am using postgres @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks you answer solves the problem, as explained, the issue is  not just related to nullable foreign key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Databases will ignore NULL when checking uniqness, it thus means that two `NULL`s are not considered braching uniqness.

You can make use of the constraint framework to check uniqness conditionally:

```
from django.db.models import Q, UniqueConstraint

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='children',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['name', 'parent'], name='name_unique'
            ),
            UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['name'], condition=Q(parent=None), name='name_unique2'
            )
        ]
```

Here if the `parent` is thus `NULL`, we check the uniqness of `name`. Some databases however might not enforce such checks.

Appartently on Microsoft's SQL Server, this is not the case, as [@Melvyn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63106061/unique-together-is-not-working-with-self-referencing-foreign-key/63106262?noredirect=1#comment111609284_63106262) says. In this case that would be wanted behavior. But often it is, in my humble opinion, unwanted behavior. `NULL` is often used exactly for this purpose.

Comment: One exception to the rule that NULL is not a value (but the absence of one) is Microsoft SQL Server. Makes working with nullable one to one fields a challenge.